# Apache Async http client performance vs sync client

Tags: asynchronous, io, apache-httpclient-4.x, nonblocking

I am trying to switch my application to the async version from apache http-components client . The goal is to be able to handle more outbound connections (in the near future). 
The payload of the requests is quite small (<5KB)
The endpoints I hit are around 20 in number.

With sync version of apache http client, the through put is about 200 requests/sec.
The average response time is about 100ms/request.
I abort the requests after a max of 180ms.

After switching to Async, the response time went up by 20ms/request.
The throughput also reduced to 160/sec. The number of aborted requests doubled.

This is after fine tuning the application a lot.
Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of async client?
I set maxConnectionsPerRoute high. Have a large Connection pool.

Are there any params that are key to getting the most out of async client?

Comment: With a small to medium number of concurrent connections classic HttpClient can be expected to be 10% to 20% faster compared to HttpAsysncClient.

Comment: How many concurrent connections are considered to be small/medium? In my case, its around 400 requests/sec. Where does the overhead come from? Would this be the same behavior for any async http client? thanks in advance.

Comment: < 500. NIO generally tends to be slower that classic I/O for small number of connections. Please do not confuse request per second and concurrent connections. These are different metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to set maxConnTotal?

The default maxConnTotal is 20, this is a global limit.

I forgot to set it once.